# Overlap of tags or topics between Sanskrit SE proposal and Hinduism SE

Tags: discussion

Here is the [link](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/109951/sanskrit-language) to the *Sanskrit* language SE proposal.

The scope is defined as: Proposed Q&A site for linguists, etymologists, Sanskrit language enthusiasts and those learning Sanskrit.

This will also include questions on Sanskrit literature and Sanskrit religious texts i.e. *Hinduism* texts. Although, these questions will mainly be from the point of view of language.

My question is whether there will be overlap of topics and tags between these two sites. If so, what overlap can you imagine? Also, is this overlap congenial or conflicting?

PS: This question also serves as a promotion for the Sanskrit SE proposal which is the fastest growing amongst the new proposals. So, do join if interested. :)

Comment: First: You proposal currently is far from completion. Second : Overlap is not a new thing over SE and there are so many discussion over it in main meta and individual sites. Even Buddhism and Hinduism also had overlap. Rule for overlap is, its' OP's choice where he want to post his questions and intentional cross post is not allowed.

Comment: Relevant question to read : [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu)

Comment: @AnkitSharma : Thanks, that is good to know. So, I can continue with working on the proposal without worrying about overlap.

Comment: c. 2020 the proposal for that suggested site has been dropped. Thank you